# Getting the links of elements without href in html

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Please see this sample Google Map user url:
https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100769636393859153985/reviews/@29.6924522,-77.6704213,5z/data=!4m3!8m2!3m1!1e1?hl=en-US&entry=ttu

**Goal**: get the urls for each of the places reviewed by the user.

**Problem**: while each review block looks clickable upon cursor hover, there is no link to be found in the html:

[image]

So, what I have to resort to is to :

1. scroll down  all the way on the user page so that all those buttons highlighted in the screenshot above are visible, and save them to a list.
2. iterate over the buttons list created above and

2.1) click on a button in each iteration, which redirects to this place details page:
[image]

2.2) click on the PLACE DETAILS button which redirects to the place's page

2.3) wait for the url to change from the user url to the place url

2.4) grab the current driver url. Done with this place!

Issue: turning a blind sight to the extra steps involved above, the main massive issue is that
as soon as I leave the user page in step 2.1 to go to the place page, the list of buttons from step 1 becomes stale and the next iteration in step 2.1 will yiled a "stale element" error since it won't find the button. So,for every iteration, I have to reload the user page and redo step 1 and continue the iteration.  The issue is that some users have hundreds of reviews and thus step 1 may take 10s of seconds to scroll all the way down to grab the fresh list of buttons in **each iteration**. This scrolling time is the **main issue** in this workaround (the required sleeps after the scrolls constitute 80% of the script's run time).

So, my questions are:

A) isn't any way to get all the links from the initial user url page without going to each place url? (how is it even possible that the reviews look clickable when you hover the curso over them manually but there is no link in the html?!!)

B) if not, is there anyway not to have to do step 1 for each iteration? That is, getting the list of all buttons in a way that they don't go stale when we get back to the user page to go to the next reviewed place page?

Here's simplified, working code for the demonstration example above. Please let it get at least the first 20 place urls for you to see how much time the scrolling increasingly takes. The steps described above are commented in the code as well for cross reference:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import re

user_url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100769636393859153985/reviews/@29.6924522,-77.6704213,5z/data=!4m3!8m2!3m1!1e1?hl=en-US&entry=ttu'
reviews_scrollable_div_css = 'div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf'
review_container_class = "jftiEf fontBodyMedium"

options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(log_level=0).install(), options=options)

driver.get(user_url)

response = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') 

reviews = response.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(review_container_class)) 
reviews_len = len(reviews) # this is when the user url is just opened and this will be always 10 at this point since that is how many reviews are displayed initially

# scrolling the reviews div all the way down to get the max number of reviews to know how many total reviews are there to iterate over later
while True: 
    scrollable_div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(reviews_scrollable_div_css)
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable_div) #scroll to the the end 
    time.sleep(4) #wait for additional reviews to load

    response = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    reviews = response.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(review_container_class)) # find all review divs

    if  reviews_len == len(reviews):  # if len(reviews) did not change after the last scroll, break because it must be the end of the scrollable div
        break
    else: 
        reviews_len = len(reviews)

# get the list of all place buttons (step 1 in the question description)                 
place_buttons_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@role = 'button'][@class = 'jftiEf fontBodyMedium t2Acle FwTFEc azD0p']")
n_place_buttons_list = len(place_buttons_list) 
print(f'found a total of {n_place_buttons_list} places reviewed')

for i in range(n_place_buttons_list): #click on each place in the reviews and get the url of the place
    driver.get(user_url) # have to reload the page since the place_buttons_list created above will go stale each time the driver leaves the user_url

    if n_place_buttons_list > 10: # the user page shows at least 10 reviews when loaded without needing to scroll
        
        # have to recreate the place_buttons_list in each iteration since user_url was reloaded
        place_buttons_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@role = 'button'][@class = 'jftiEf fontBodyMedium t2Acle FwTFEc azD0p']")

        while len(place_buttons_list) < i+1: # if the index of the place were are working on is larger than the number of reviews currently visible, scroll down once
            scrollable_div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(reviews_scrollable_div_css)
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable_div)
            time.sleep(4)
            place_buttons_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@role = 'button'][@class = 'jftiEf fontBodyMedium t2Acle FwTFEc azD0p']")
    
    place_buttons_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'd4r55 YJxk2d']")

    #removed try/except for brevity
    place_buttons_list[i].click() #click on the place button, step 2.1
    time.sleep(1)
    place_details_button =  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class = 'lzIite PpaGLb']")))                        
    place_details_button.click()   # click on the PLACE DETAILS button, step 2.2
    time.sleep(2) # it takes a bit for the url to change from the user url to the place url, step 2.3
    url_place = driver.current_url # get the place url, step 2.4
    print(f'url of the place reviewed #{i}: {url_place}')
```

Comment: You could write you own wait() function but the time saved will be marginal. You could also split this Test into 2 steps.  Within your first iteration you could only store the names of visited places into a list. And after all places are covered, loop through the list and visit the place details page and extract your desired data. A few time.sleep could be avoided that way, but it probably takes a little time to implement.